# Empty Window in Pyglet

Tags: python, opengl, pyglet

I had the following problem - the first time compiling this label is displayed correctly, but the next time I only get an empty black window.

```
import pyglet
window = pyglet.window.Window()

label = pyglet.text.Label('Hello, world',
                          font_name='Times New Roman',
                          font_size=36,
                          x=window.width//2, y=window.height//2,
                          anchor_x='center', anchor_y='center')

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    label.draw()

pyglet.app.run()
```

I use python 3.4, how I can fix it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This code actually works running Python 3.5.1 using Pyglet 1.2.2.
However, trying to add a manual frame buffer will cause a black window.

```
import pyglet
window = pyglet.window.Window()

label = pyglet.text.Label('Hello, world',
                          font_name='Times New Roman',
                          font_size=36,
                          x=window.width//2, y=window.height//2,
                          anchor_x='center', anchor_y='center')

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    label.draw()
    window.flip()  # <-- New addition

pyglet.app.run()
```

I figured this all boils down to a timing issue in the graphical buffer where things might get updated before you see the text begin cleared again.

So in order to avoid this, I'll paste a minimal example of how you can inherit the pyglet window class in your own custom class where you call the events and re-draw's yourself.

```
import pyglet

class base(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super(base, self).__init__(600, 600, fullscreen = False)

        self.alive = 1
        self.label = pyglet.text.Label('Hello, world',
                          font_name='Times New Roman',
                          font_size=36,
                          x=self.width//2, y=self.height//2,
                          anchor_x='center', anchor_y='center')
    def on_draw(self):
        self.render()

    def render(self):
        self.clear()
        self.label.draw()
        self.flip()

    def on_close(self):
        self.alive = 0

    def on_key_press(self, symbol, modifiers):
        if symbol == pyglet.window.key.ESCAPE: # [ESC]
            self.alive = 0

    def run(self):
        while self.alive == 1:
            self.render()

            # -----------> This is key <----------
            # This is what replaces pyglet.app.run()
            # but is required for the GUI to not freeze
            #
            event = self.dispatch_events()

x = base()
x.run()
```

This code is also more efficient than the standard way of using decorators for a number of resons, but most imporantly it appears to work around the timing issues that you discovered.